# micro-orm FilterQuery error for mongo DAO function

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, clean-architecture, micro-orm

Using Micro-ORM **5.7**.
I have an entity defined as

```
class User {
  @PrimaryKey({ type: 'varchar', length: 250 })
  private id: string;

  @Property({ name: 'first_name', length: 50 })
  private first_name: string;
```

Have a DAO layer something like-

```
@injectable()
export default class UserDAO {
  private async getUserRepository(): Promise<EntityRepository<User>> {
    const repository = await this.getRepository<User>(User);
    return repository;
  }

  public async findByUserId(id: string): Promise<User> {
    const repository = await this.getUserRepository();
    const user = (await repository.findOne({ id })) as User;
    return user;
  }
}
```

But this always gives error for `await repository.findOne({ id })` as

**Argument of type '{ id: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FilterQuery'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'id' does not exist in type 'FilterQuery'.**

User has **ID** as PK then not able to understand why TS is saying `'id' does not exist in type 'FilterQuery<User>'`

Comment: Why would your ID column be private?